# rotating views in iPad app based on orientation changes

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an iPad app which has a number of UIViews and images loaded with in it. It works fine in one orientation, but now I need to make it work for all orientations.
I am subscribing to the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification. 
now once I know which direction the device is oriented towards, I have to reset the UI.
what I am doing right now is manually going through each UIView and changes its origin point, and then whatever is within that view I reconfigure its origin points too. is there a simpler way to just rotate the view around? 
Example :

```
         - (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
         {
             UIDeviceOrientation oriantation;
             newOrientation=[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
             switch (newOrientation) {
                   case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
                            CGRect landscaperight = self.view.frame;
                            landscaperight.origin.x -= 768;
                            self.view.frame = landscaperight;
               break; 
         }
```

the problem here is that I have a lot of views to work with, so any simpler way of handling
this task would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have you created your views programmatically or in IB?

Comment: no its all programmatically. and some of them are buttons that when pressed will show custom menu pages.

Answer (score 0):

One fundamental piece of making autorotation work is setting the [`autoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) on your views.

You can do that either visually in IB, or programmatically like this:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

The code above will make your window fit to its superview while keeping the left, right, top, and bottom margin unchanged. Depending on what king of views you are using in your app, you might require using other resizing flags to make your margin flexible (i.e., move when the orientation changes to adapt the overall interface).

This approach will work on all iOS versions.

A technique that I found useful in connection with `autoresizingMask` is the use of container views that have the only aim of keeping together a set of subviews. E.g., a set of controls that should be displayed on the same row at a fixed distance from the top margin: you put the controls inside of a container view; then let them "move freely" within the container view (by setting flexible top/bottom/left/right margin; at the same time you make the container view "stick" to the position you want.

Apart from this general hints, it is not possible to say anything more concrete without knowing what you are trying to do and what issues you have found.

If you are supporting only iOS6, you could use [Auto Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2).